# @Input and @Output are always undefined in Angular-Cli

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

Whatever values are inside the individuals are printed without issues but whatever is obtained using @Input or @Output is not displayed.

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-input',
  templateUrl: './form-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-input.component.scss']
})

export class FormInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() fieldType: string;
    //with another Input and 1 Output DOM

 constructor(
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.fieldType);
    }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-form-input (value)="action($event)"
    [fieldType]="date"
    [maxAllowItem]="1">
</app-form-input>
```

Is there anything goes wrong in syntax?
The Log always show 'undefined' in all cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is trying to pull in a variable defined within your component.

Try the following syntax, wrap the string again, this should ensure you are passing a string and not a variable from the component, the input will then know to expect a string.

```
[fieldType]="'date'"
```

This is wrapping the string in `"` and `'`.

Comment: Thanks for the your explanation. it works fine now.

Comment: glad I could help, please consider marking as accepted answer if your issue is resolved :-)

Comment: a shorter solution, if the value is always the same, is to use `fieldType="date"` instead.

Comment: very valid point, please feel free to edit into the answer :-)

Comment: @Supamiu Thanks for your answer. May I know what's the difference between them?

Comment: I think its just syntax, will both end up passing the data into the child, though [fieldType] will take a dynamic value like a component variable.

Comment: @TLee It's mainly to distinguish easily what's static from what's dynamic like dince12 explained :)

Comment: I will make an edit soon just need to find some docs that word the difference well

Answer (score 0):

You may need to initialize the initial values of your `@Input` and `@Output` variables inside your component because `@Input` properties will be `undefined` unless they are provided from outside and `@Output` properties need to be initialized with `EventEmitter`

Also you need to check the values inside [`ngOnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges#ngOnChanges) which will be executed during Change Detection

Your code will be like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-input',
  templateUrl: './form-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-input.component.scss']
})

export class FormInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() fieldType: string;
    @Output() event: EventEmitter<any>
    //with another Input and 1 Output DOM

    constructor() {
       this.fieldType = ''
       this.event = new EventEmitter()
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }
    ngOnChanges() { // <- it will run every time and give you the latest value of fieldType
      console.log(this.fieldType);
    }
}
```